# Asp.net processing of .CFM files or Redirects from .cfm to .aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, coldfusion

I have a legacy .cfm (ColdFusion) page which used to process form data (from remote servers) and send users emails based on form data. Now I no longer use ColdFusion and instead hosting is at the 'free' ASP.NET (3.5). I am not sure how much control I have over that. But I was thinking if I can have a global.asax file where all requests (actually, form posts) going to the .cfm page get redirected to an aspx page where I can do the needed processing.
How can this be done within a shared hosting providers limitations? I know I can create a Virtual Directory in IIS. For example, www.xyz.com/processform.cfm can be directed to www.xyz.com/processform.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Koby Mizrahy was close to helping me. My problem was that I was running Blog Engine .NET 2.0 as the main application of my website in GoDaddy's IIS Classic Mode. So the .cfm extension were not processed by the ASP.NET engine and hence no changes to either Web.Config or Global.asax were helping. I had to change to Integrated mode. Here is what I did to fix:

In Web.Config, added this in the 'Handlers' node to make sure Form Posts to .cfm would be processed, otherwise I got some 405 error.

```
 <add name="ColdFusion" path="*.cfm" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" preCondition="integratedMode" />
```

Then in global.asax, I had this in the Application_beginrequest handler

```
if (Request.Url.ToString().Contains("TourEmail-act.cfm"))// 
    {
   Server.Transfer("/360Flash/TourEmail-act.aspx");
   }
 }
```

Problem solved! Thank you very much Mizrahy!

Comment: One more thing: I had to remove the following from the web.config file because it was generating some 'encoding' error:  <add name="CompressionModule" type="BlogEngine.Core.Web.HttpModules.CompressionModule, BlogEngine.Core"/>

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways to do it:

If you want to map each cfm file to an aspx page you can do it by adding the urlMapping collection to system.web section:

```
<system.web>
    <urlMappings>
        <add url="~/mypage.cfm" mappedUrl="~/mypage.aspx"/>
    </urlMappings>
</system.web>
```

If you want to globally handle any request for .cfm file You can do it in global.asax in the Begin request event:

```
 protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        if(HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension == ".cfm")
        {
            // Do what ever you need to do
        }
 }
```

Both ways are not dependent on the host so godaddy is not a problem.

In the first option the form data will be maintained whily in the second option you will have to write the logic to pass the form data to the page you want to redirect.

If I am not wrong,  but I am not sure, maybe Server.Transfer maintains form data

Comment: Hi, I am still working on it. A complicated factor is that it is Flash Player running on remote servers which sends Form Post data to http://www.xyz.com/xxx.cfm page and so far your solution is not working. I am trying to simulate an the Post from an aspx page first...

Comment: I don't think your solution is going to work as it is. I am getting an error when posting from a remote server. The error page indeed shows the url of the target server with the .cfm page the error is: 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.
The page you are looking for cannot be displayed because an invalid method (HTTP verb) was used to attempt access.
The web.config is refusing absolute URL and that's why perhaps the redirect is failing? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the relevant section of the web.config ?

Comment: <!-- URL Redirects for .CFM Posts. . -->
      <urlMappings>
          <add url="~/360Flash/TourEmail-act.cfm" mappedUrl="~/EmailTest.aspx"/>
      </urlMappings>
  </system.web>

Comment: I am trying your global.asax solution as well. But neither work:  if (HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension == ".cfm")
       // if (HttpContext.Current.Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath.Contains(".cfm")) in case of 'Contains' server transfer does not work. In case of your original 'if', there is actually an error

Comment: It looks ok. The url are just how they supposed to be (starts with ~). To narrow down the problem could you please do a quick check where you put non-existing cfm file url and exsiting aspx file and check if you are tranferring to the aspx by default ? (without posting or anything

Comment: I just so in your question that you are using framework 3.5 and I am using 4.0. I haven't checked compatability of my answer to framework 3.5... I will do it later and update you

Comment: If I do:  <urlMappings>
          <add url="~/blah.cfm" mappedUrl="~/default.aspx"/>
      </urlMappings>
  </system.web> then I get an error: Object reference not set ... [Thank you very much for your help!]

Comment: Update to my previous comment: If I enable compilation debug to true then the error becomes: 500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10931/discussion-between-koby-mizrahy-and-meengla)

Comment: I think the answer of web.config probably would have worked but may be it is GoDaddy's restriction on .cfm file and/or something in the compiled BlogEngine 2/0 engine (I know, its older version but got to stick with .NET 3.5) causing any request going to .cfm to get redirected to default.aspx page. Thanks a bunch anyway. I learned some new things today.

Comment: GoDaddy uses II7 and hence urlmapping in web.config is not working, according to this: http://forums.asp.net/t/1523272.aspx/2/10 I need to find a way around it....