# Coldfusion to .NET pages .cfm to .aspx in Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, redirect, coldfusion, iis-7.5

Creating redirects for Coldfusion pages to .Net pages through web.config.  Looking for guidance on handling .cfm request and converting them to .aspx on a windows server with IIS 7.5.  Ideally 301 redirects for SEO purposes.

Anyone know an efficient way to handle .cfm request and convert them to .aspx through web.config?

Comment: You can find guidance if you ask specific questions, Grasshopper.

Comment: Probably better suited for ServerFault

Comment: Can you pls augment your question to be formed of grammatically correct & comprehensible sentences, and ask a specific question. But i am inclined to agree with Scott: this doesn't sound like a programming question, it's a server config question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I work with Coldfusion 9.x.x on IIS 7.5 and 8 and here is what we do.

**Say you have a link that appears like this:**

`http://example.com/index.cfm?articleid=12&displayText=title-of-the-article`

**You'll need this basic structure added to your web.config file:**

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Article Stripper" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^([\w-_+]+)/([\w-_+]+)" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.cfm?articleid={R:1}&amp;displayText={R:2}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>             
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**To produce something like this:**

`http://example.com/12/title-of-the-article`

Answer (score 0):

You can do using Application_BeginRequest() event in Global.asax.

Please check out following link for further details on it.

[Asp.net processing of .CFM files or Redirects from .cfm to .aspx page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470740/asp-net-processing-of-cfm-files-or-redirects-from-cfm-to-aspx-page)